# Why Azure table storage data loading slow in my Android app?

Tags: android, azure

I have created Android app with Azure table storage data..I Will open every time my app Azure data loading in slow..
My table `mBranchListTable = mClient.getTable(BranchList.class);`

my `RemoteDataTask()` code

```
 private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Branchs.this);

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            final List<BranchList> results = mBranchListTable.where().field("enable").eq(val(true)).orderBy("sort", QueryOrder.Ascending).execute().get();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    for (BranchList item : results) {
                        mAdapter.add(item);

                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");

        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

### OnCreate

```
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    mAdapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item);
    ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LViewBranchList);
    listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: slow means what???  May be your data is loading at normal speed but you might have did something wrong in Async task and all . post your code which you are using to update UI.

Comment: what i asking whenever open my app data loading too long. if any posible code for get speed.

Comment: post your code  of Async task . I am also using azure and It,s working fine , may be you are wrong somewhere while updating UI.

Comment: Not only this session..normally Azure data loading very too long my app.

Comment: from where did you get this code . post a link plzzz

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-listview-tutorial/      I m modify this code..